# convert dataframe to excel and download

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask

I have created a flask application where it take excel file and it cleans the data and gives the output in excel file. basically what happens is user uploads the excel file after submitting browser should download the filtered excel file. 
can someone suggest me references? I need to know how to set the path. I tried converting it into the HTML by using but this code doesn't download but it automatically saves the cleaned file as HTML.

```
    data1 = df.to_html()
    #write html to file 
    text_file = open("data1.html", "w") 
    text_file.write(data1) 
    text_file.close()
    return render_template("success.html", name = text_file)
```

Comment: hard to understand how this situation looks like, maybe this will helps https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that receive an input file, read it with `pandas`, process it (with a `make_processing()` function I created) and return it as .csv. Is almost the same for an excel file.

```
    file = request.files['file']
    content = file.read()
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(content))
    df2 = make_processing(df)
    si = io.StringIO()
    df2.to_csv(si, index=False, encoding='utf8')
    output = flask.make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename=periodicidad.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

Comment: does this work if i deploy it on cloud(pythonanywhere.com) ?

Comment: can you share the repository of your app ?

Comment: Is not a public app, this is the most important part of the code. I deployed my app in AWS, it should work with any hosting service.